# How to change Clock Color and Ok button fontColor in TimePicker - MUI React

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, timepicker

I'm trying to change some properties like Clock Color and Ok button fontColor in TimePicker using the css className properties, but with no success. Does anyone knows how to do change it using sx or slotProps?

```
<TimePicker
          ampm={false}
          views={['hours', 'minutes', 'seconds']}
          sx={{
            backgroundColor: "#333335",
            font: "white",
            color: "#FFFF",
            textDecoration: "bold",
            input: {
              color: "#FFFF",
              fontSize: "1.4rem",
            },
              "& .MuiTimePicker-root": {
              backgroundColor: "#222223",
            },
            "& .MuiTimePicker-input": {
              color: "#FFFF",
              fontSize: "1.2rem",
            },
          }}
          slotProps={{
            popper: {
              sx: {
                "& .MuiList-root": {
                  backgroundColor: "#333335",
                },
                "& .MuiMenuItem-root": {
                  "&.Mui-selected": {
                    backgroundColor: "#04395E",
                    color: "white"
                  },
                  color: "white"
                },
                "& .MuiDialogActions-root": {
                  backgroundColor: "#333335",
                },
                "& .MuiSvgIcon-root": {
                  "&.MuiSvgIcon-fontSizeMedium": {
                    backgroundColor: "#04395E",
                    color: "white"
                  },
                  color: "white"
                },
              },
            },
          }}
          value={selectedTime}
          onChange={(newTime: any) => setSelectedTime(newTime)}
          timeSteps={{hours: 1, minutes: 1, seconds: 1}}
/>
```

Here's a image showing the elements that I want to change the color
[image: TimePicker]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the following to the `sx` property on the `TimePicker` to change the color of the clock icon.

```js
"& .MuiSvgIcon-root": {
  color: "white"
},
```

and for the **OK** text button you can use the following on the `sx` property of the `popper`

```js
"& .MuiDialogActions-root .MuiButton-text": {
  color: "white"
}
```